# clang-format: Stop breaking long methods up

Tags: objective-c, clang-format

In attempting to set up a .clang-format file for a project using Objective-C, I've run into an issue where, even with 0 maximum line width, long Objective-C methods are getting cut into multiple lines. For example, this:

```
AFHTTPRequestOperation *returnOperation = [self POST:endpoint parameters:nil constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {
        [formData appendPartWithFormData:[[secureStore valueForKey:storeKey] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] name:tokenKey];
        if ([provider isEqualToString:kTwitterKey]) {
            [formData appendPartWithFormData:[[secureStore twitterSecretToken] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] name:kTwitterSecretKey];
            [formData appendPartWithFormData:[email dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] name:kEmailKey];
        }
        [formData appendPartWithFormData:[[secureStore token] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] name:tokenKey];
    } success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSDictionary *response) {
        [secureStore setToken:response[kTokenKey]];
        if (completionHandler) {
            completionHandler(nil, response);
        }
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        if (completionHandler) {
            completionHandler(error, nil);
        }
    }];
```

gets turned into this:

```
AFHTTPRequestOperation *returnOperation = [self POST:endpoint
        parameters:nil
        constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {
          [formData appendPartWithFormData:[[secureStore valueForKey:storeKey] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] name:tokenKey];
          if ([provider isEqualToString:kTwitterKey]) {
              [formData appendPartWithFormData:[[secureStore twitterSecretToken] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] name:kTwitterSecretKey];
              [formData appendPartWithFormData:[email dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] name:kEmailKey];
          }
          [formData appendPartWithFormData:[[secureStore token] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] name:kTokenKey];
        }
        success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSDictionary *response) {
          [secureStore setToken:response[kTokenKey]];
          if (completionHandler) {
              completionHandler(nil, response);
          }
        }
        failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
          if (completionHandler) {
              completionHandler(error, nil);
          }
        }];
```

I'd like to leave the splitting of methods into multiple lines to the developer but still have the formatter check for proper brace placement, for example. Suggestions for how to fix that weird interior indention would also be appreciated.

Edit:
Here's my .clang-format file, if anyone's interested. I'm trying to replicate the New York Times Objective-C styles, mostly.

```
---
Language: Cpp
AccessModifierOffset: -2
AlignAfterOpenBracket: false
AlignEscapedNewlinesLeft: false
AlignOperands: false
AlignTrailingComments: true
AllowAllParametersOfDeclarationOnNextLine: false
AllowShortBlocksOnASingleLine: false
AllowShortCaseLabelsOnASingleLine: false
AllowShortFunctionsOnASingleLine: false
AllowShortIfStatementsOnASingleLine: false
AllowShortLoopsOnASingleLine: false
AlwaysBreakAfterDefinitionReturnType: false
AlwaysBreakBeforeMultilineStrings: false
AlwaysBreakTemplateDeclarations: false
BinPackArguments: true
BinPackParameters: true
BreakBeforeBinaryOperators: false
BreakBeforeBraces: Stroustrup
BreakBeforeTernaryOperators: false
BreakConstructorInitializersBeforeComma: false
ColumnLimit: 0
CommentPragmas: '^ IWYU pragma:'
ConstructorInitializerAllOnOneLineOrOnePerLine: false
ConstructorInitializerIndentWidth: 4
ContinuationIndentWidth: 4
Cpp11BracedListStyle: true
DerivePointerAlignment: false
ExperimentalAutoDetectBinPacking: false
IndentCaseLabels: true
IndentWrappedFunctionNames: false
IndentWidth: 4
KeepEmptyLinesAtTheStartOfBlocks: false
MaxEmptyLinesToKeep: 1
NamespaceIndentation: None
ObjCBlockIndentWidth: 4
ObjCSpaceAfterProperty: true
ObjCSpaceBeforeProtocolList: false
PenaltyBreakBeforeFirstCallParameter: 0
PenaltyBreakComment: 0
PenaltyBreakFirstLessLess: 0
PenaltyBreakString: 0
PenaltyExcessCharacter: 0
PenaltyReturnTypeOnItsOwnLine: 0
PointerAlignment: Right
SpaceAfterCStyleCast: false
SpaceBeforeAssignmentOperators: true
SpaceBeforeParens: ControlStatements
SpaceInEmptyParentheses: false
SpacesBeforeTrailingComments: 1
SpacesInAngles: false
SpacesInContainerLiterals: true
SpacesInCStyleCastParentheses: false
SpacesInParentheses: false
SpacesInSquareBrackets: false
Standard: Cpp11
TabWidth: 8
UseTab: Never
```

Comment: I have the same issue as well! The weird part is: It worked perfectly with setting ColumnLimit to 0 a while ago. Now I have this forced multi-line mess as well, which is driving me insane!

Comment: I've noticed the same thing, it seems that clang-format 3.7 has different behaviour in where it places newlines - I'm also looking for a solution for this, but temporarily I've switched to an older version of clang-format - if you use clang-format Xcode this then commit will work as before https://github.com/travisjeffery/ClangFormat-Xcode/tree/c8343aa596bf96c8afa5cc4bfc3728227ace1224

Comment: We can track the bug reported about this on ClangFormat-Xcode here: https://github.com/travisjeffery/ClangFormat-Xcode/issues/81

Comment: While not specifically addressing your question — we’ve had some issues with clang-format and moved to Uncrustify + [BBUncrustifyPlugin](https://github.com/benoitsan/BBUncrustifyPlugin-Xcode) with great success

Answer (score 2):

I'm using the following config which will not break up the long method

```
BasedOnStyle: LLVM
IndentWidth: 4
AllowShortIfStatementsOnASingleLine: true
IndentCaseLabels: false
ColumnLimit: 0
```

And you can get the LLVM setting using the command

```
clang-format -style=llvm -dump-config > .clang-format
```

Comment: `ColumnLimit` did the job!

Comment: also setting `AlwaysBreakBeforeMultilineStrings` to false will keep your function calls, macros, etc that call literals from breaking!

Comment: @Paschalis In my machine, the default llvm clang-format has already set `AlwaysBreakBeforeMultilineStrings : false`

Comment: I already have all of this set and am a bit hesitant to reinclude a style. Which setting would this depend on?

Comment: @Alper Like the file says, based on LLVM. And the plugin for Xcode I used is https://github.com/travisjeffery/ClangFormat-Xcode